# How do I exercise my Visual Studio 2013 downgrade rights?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a copy of Visual Studio 2013, and while I mostly use it, I have to work with one particular C++ SDK that does not yet officially support Visual Studio 2013, so I'm looking to install Visual Studio 2012 using my Visual Studio downgrade rights.

According to the Microsoft Licensing Information, this should be possible:

> For Visual Studio Professional, the software included in the license is the current version of the software, Visual Studio Professional 2013, **plus downgrade rights to simultaneously run prior versions of Visual Studio Professional to which you may otherwise have access.**

(emphasis mine)

I have access to a copy of Visual Studio 2012, however I'm still being asked for a license key (which I guess is to be expected). How can I license my copy of Visual Studio 2012 using my Visual Studio 2013 license (if at all)?

Comment: Did you get your copies of VS through MSDN Subscriptions?

Comment: No, the licenses are bought individually.

Comment: https://readytogo.microsoft.com/en-us/Asset/_layouts/Download.aspx?SourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freadytogo.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2FAsset%2FRTG%20Anonymous%20Asset%20Library%2F05%20Visual%20Studio%202013%20-%20VS2013%20and%20MSDN%20Licensing%20Whitepaper.pdf does seem to imply that if you buy Visual Studio Professional 2013 (separate to an MSDN subscription) you can exercise downgrade rights.

Comment: you should contact microsoft

Answer (score 1):

> For Visual Studio Professional

Professional includes an MSDN subscription.  Which gives you access to lots of older versions of Visual Studio.  Not all of them, VS6 was removed as part of the settlement with Sun over Java.  Make sure you [activated the subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/dd364989.aspx), then visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions

You can download VS2012 there.  Note that it is *different* from the one you already have, the one you download will not ask for an activation key.

Comment: Are you sure? The retail version of VS2013 ("Visual Studio Professional" - US$499) seems distinctly different http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/Visual-Studio-Professional-2013/productID.284832200 from http://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/products/visual-studio-professional-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_PricingHeader US$1199

Comment: I spoke with the person that purchased the copies of VS2013, and they are certain that MSDN was not included. Presumably it was purchased through a reseller.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exercise your downgrade rights because you don't have it.

You are referring to msdn downgrade rights but you are not an msdn subscribers.

it is written in the bold text you post:

this is the classical  language of legal documents:

> **to which you may otherwise have access.**

It means if in the package you buy there are older version then you can use it

**you may have access** not  **you have access**

Comment: https://readytogo.microsoft.com/en-us/Asset/_layouts/Download.aspx?SourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freadytogo.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2FAsset%2FRTG%20Anonymous%20Asset%20Library%2F05%20Visual%20Studio%202013%20-%20VS2013%20and%20MSDN%20Licensing%20Whitepaper.pdf refers to Visual Studio with MSDN and Visual Studio Professional separately. And the Visual Studio Professional part is quoted by the OP.

Comment: @ta.speot.is yes I read it. it means that he may not that he have